# Splatting subproperty?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to splat arguments from a subproperty?

For example, here is sample function to illustrate:

```
function Get-Pow{
    param(
        [int]$x,
        [int]$y
        ) 
    [Math]::Pow($x,$y)
}
```

this function can be call using:

```
$args = @{ x=10; y=2 }
Get-Pow @args # outputs 100
```

this can also be called using a simple iteration:

```
$powsOfTen = @(
    @{ x=10; y=1 }
    @{ x=10; y=2 }
    @{ x=10; y=3 }
)

foreach($p in $powsOfTen){
    Get-Pow @p # Outputs 10,100,1000
}
```

However, if the arguments hashtable is from a subproperty, it does not works:

```
$valuesToCompute = @(
    @{ Id=1; Arguments = @{ x = 10; y= 1} }
    @{ Id=2; Arguments = @{ x = 10; y= 2} }
    @{ Id=3; Arguments = @{ x = 10; y= 3} }

)

foreach($valueToCompute in $valuesToCompute){
    Write-Host $valueToCompute.Id
    Get-pow @($valueToCompute.Arguments) 
}
```

How should I call my function when args are from a subproperty?

I tried `@valueToCompute.Arguments`, I tried `$args = $valueToCompute.Arguments; Get-Pow @args`, but nothing I tried work.

Comment: Your problem is not with lack of ability but lack of *syntax*. This is currently being addressed in PowerShell [RFC0002-Generalized-Splatting](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/blob/master/1-Draft/RFC0002-Generalized-Splatting.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
function Get-Pow{
    param(
        [int]$x,
        [int]$y
        ) 
    [Math]::Pow($x,$y)
}

$valuesToCompute = @(
    @{ Id=1; Arguments = @{ x = 10; y= 1} }
    @{ Id=2; Arguments = @{ x = 10; y= 2} }
    @{ Id=3; Arguments = @{ x = 10; y= 3} }

)

foreach($valueToCompute in $valuesToCompute){
    Write-Host $valueToCompute.Id
    $splat = $valueToCompute.Arguments;
    Get-pow @splat
}
```

Note that by my reading of [the splatting doc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx), `@Args` is a reserved variable.  See the section "SPLATTING COMMAND PARAMETERS".

Comment: actually I realized my issue were somewhere else. I once tried your syntax, but it didn't worked. The culprit, though, was on the args I passed. My real function didn't get correct parameters. Anyways, thanks